# Single-page all-JavaScript dynamic website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript, single-page-application

I am currently taking over a project for a client that has an already-built website.

The site is similar to a "twitter" type site where you create accounts, can post 'tweets', and have followers.

I have looked at the website code and it is a single file that consists entirely of JavaScript. Included in the JavaScript code is functionality to sign up, edit a profile, and show an "about us" page.

I have been creating websites since 1996 and have never seen anyone try to  do something like this.

Here are my questions:

1. What are the **advantages** of running a website that consists of a single page whose entire content is JavaScript?
2. What are the **disadvantages**?
3. Does anyone know of a current website that is constructed as described in my question? (Preferably a dynamic site with profiles.)

Answer (score 1):

[Single-Page Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) are quite common nowadays. The main advantage is much faster display, without having to re-render and entire page when only a portion of it has changed. JavaScript on both the server (e.g. using node.js) and the client means only one language to learn, and increased interoperability between client and server components.

Disadvantages may include difficulties bookmarking individual pages and using the browser's back/forward buttons (but that can easily be solved with plugins like history.js, inability for search engine to index the page (which is why SPAs are mostly used for desktop-like applications where SEO isn't a concern), increased memory consumption by the browser, and increased time to load.

[ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs3/) is a UI framework for desktop-like web applications. A very popular and modern client-server frameworks for developing such applications is [meteor](http://meteor.com).

Comment: Thanks Dan! One more follow up question. How would something like this handle a highly trafficked site? Would a single page js setup be able to handle high traffic loads vs php/mysql?

Comment: Of course. meteor's blog handled a lot of traffic from HackerNews. node.js is [wicked fast](http://chetansurpur.com/blog/2010/10/why-node-js-is-totally-awesome.html), and you can use MySQL as the database backend for an SPA as well. Since the site will only request minimal amounts of data from the server (see meteor's [data on the wire](http://docs.meteor.com/#sevenprinciples) principle), you may very well end up with a faster site overall.